# Laravel Mongo GroupBy And count in an efficient manner

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent, aggregation-framework

I have an `authors` collection that has a many-to-many relation to a `posts` collection. The `posts` collection has a `category` field which can be, for example, "Suspense", "Drama", "Action", etc.

I need to go through my entire `posts` collection and group by the `category` fields and also have the associated counts.

This is what I have so far:

```
 $authors = Author::where('active', true)->get();

        foreach ($authors as $author){
            foreach ($author->posts()->groupBy('category')->get() as $data){

                // Do some logic

            }
        }
```

Basically the output I am expecting is an array with `category` as keys and the counts as a value. So if I do `$a['Drama']` it gives me count of how many times that author wrote a post with that category.

I can probably figure it out by working in my loop logic above but it does not look very efficient. Should I look at aggregation? If so can someone get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$authors = DB::collection('authors')
    ->where('active', true)
    ->get();

// Laravel >= 5.3 would return collection instead of plain array
$authors = is_array($authors) ? Collection::make($authors) : $authors;

$authors->map(function ($author) {
    return $author
        ->posts()
        ->groupBy('category')
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($collection) {
            return $collection->count();
        });
});
```